# Error in C:/users/<username>

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have a users folder with name of "Kevin & Keith". I would like to rename it to just "Kevin". My issue is that whenever i try to ruin any programming command like npm install it fails stating the following error

[image: Error Message]

Also there is the following file created in my users folder.

[image: Folder]

So is there any to change the folder name or create a new user folder that can be used

Comment: It would appear that there's some incorrect quoting somewhere in NPM, so it chokes on the ampersand. (`create-react-app` is deprecated by the way, don't use it.) // Renaming profile folders isn't supported on Windows.

Comment: @DanielB Having an ampersand in my username should have an affect on other functionality of windows correct?

Comment: Just create a new user called Kevin

Comment: @Gantendo I've tried  creating a user named Kevin, it tells me "It can't be the same as PC name"

Comment: @KevinRodrigues: Renaming the PC would be the next step (it's usually harmless) – change it to "Kevin-PC" or similar.

Comment: @KevinRodrigues On Windows itself, not so much. However, mediocre Batch scripts can break easily, as with the first screenshot. But then, they can also break with mere spaces in the path, even though it’s 2024.

Answer (score -1):

There is two key for change username in windows:

- change the folder `C:\Users\{username}`. By login with  administration account can change.
- change the **regedit** value: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Profilelist\{S-1-5-????}` —— modified the value of `ProfileImagePath`

If you want to change current username, you can follow below step:

1. log out current account.
2. Log in with the Administration account. If you don't see
   Administration account, you can run command `net user administrator /active:yes` in cmd with administration power.

   [img: when you active, you can see the Administration account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rlmy.png)
3. Enter `C:\Users`, now you should have power to change the username folder.

   [img: Keydown F2 can rename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3RuC.png)

   [img: you can see the new name is valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzhni.png)
4. Keydown `win+r` to run `regedit`
5. Goto `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Profilelist`
6. And find your user key. For example, my key is "S--5-21-36...".

   [img: show the path in regedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcWMC.png)
7. Modified the value of `ProfileImagePath`, make sure the value is same as the new username you just set.
8. logout and login with you account, you can see the folder has changed.

   [img: finally result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sivu.png)

Reference:

- [Using Administrator account login](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/enable-administrator-account-windows-10/)

Comment: Please note that I tried to make your image inline, but MalwareBytes is not happy with it.  Please post the picture somewhere else, and someone will make it inline.  And a Chinese reference to an English site is useless.  Also, I don't believe you can do it this way.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta thanks. btw, I reply in the comment by this way, whether you can receive?

Comment: This is an absolutely horrible idea. There is a built-in way to rename profiles within Windows. Renaming the profile directory is a guaranteed way of breaking a user profile permanently. It also has numerous grammatical errors.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm so sorry. I didn't know the consequences of that (Although I had helped my friend using this way before and there was no problem). Can you tell me what the built-in modification method is? Thank you very much.

Comment: Windows 10 and Windows 11 allows you to connect a locate account to a Microsoft Account.  When you disconnect the Microsoft Account, with a local profile, you are presented an opporunity to provide a profile name.  This mechanic can be used to rename a user's profile directory.